# <button> unclickable in Firefox but works in chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, firefox, sass

I have the following header:

```
      <header id="app-header"
              className="fluid-container navbar navbar-default">
          <div>
            <button className={buttonClass}
                    onClick={this.openSideBar}>
              <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
      </header>
```

It uses the last stable version of react and boostrap.

I style it with some sass:

```
#app-header

      margin-bottom: 5px
      display: flex
      flex-direction: row
      height: 5rem

      div
        width: 5rem
        margin-right: -5rem  // let the h2 center align on the whole row

        button
          background: transparent
          border: none
          width: 100%
          height: 100%

          &:hover
            background: white

      h1
        height: 100%
        margin: 0
        flex: 2
        text-align: center
        font-size: 2rem
        display: flex
        align-items: center
        justify-content: center
```

I end up with a header looking like this:

[image]

The hamburger menu is clickable under chrome, but not under firefox. If I remove all sass style, the h1 goes on top of the button, but the button gets clickable in firefox.

Comment: Looks like the `margin-right: -5rem` on `#app-header div` is causing this. Try finding an alternative way, seems like Firefox places the clickable area outside the window.

Comment: Yes that's it. Make it an answer so I can give you an upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`margin-right: -5rem` on `#app-header div` is causing this. Try finding an alternative way—seems like Firefox is misinterpreting this and placing the clickable area outside the window.

Comment: Thanks. I ending up replacing it with a padding-right: 2.5rem on the h2.

Answer (score -1):

write button code like this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled="disabled">Primary button</button>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to disable it, I'm trying to make it clickable